# cudatoolkit and cudnn on anaconda vs conda-forge channels

Tags: installation, anaconda, conda, cudnn, cudatoolkit

cudatoolkit and cudnn are available on anaconda and conda-forge channels.

Is there a reason to prefer installing these from one of the channels over the other?